# How to override button's style in <Style> tag?

Tags: wpf, xaml, triggers, styles

Let suppose I have template of button's style, but I want to add to one specific button a few DataTriggers (in  tag) but I can't do that, because Style is already defined

```
<Button Style="{DynamicResource MetroCircleButtonStyle}"> 
   <Button.Style> // error - The property "Style" is set more than once
       <Style TargetType="Button">
           <Style.Triggers>

           </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Button.Style>   
 </Button>
```

How do I set `Style="{Dynamicresource MetroCircleButtonStyle}"` inside `<Style>` tag to avoid error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just "override" your "MetroCircleButtonStyle" creating a new Style based on "MetroCircleButtonStyle".

```
 <Style x:Key="MetroCircleButtonStyleWithChanges" TargetType="{x:Type Button}" BasedOn="{StaticResource MetroCircleButtonStyle}" />
```

And there do whatever you need. Then just use it:

```
<Button Style="{DynamicResource MetroCircleButtonStyleWithChanges}" />
```

---

If you aren't going to use it anymore you could just define it in the button like:

```
    <Button>
        <Button.Style>
            <Style BasedOn="MetroCircleButtonStyle" TargetType="Button">
                <!--Whatever you need-->
            </Style>
        </Button.Style>
    </Button>
```